# How to pass data model via implicit deeplink, between fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, deep-linking, implicit

I need to pass a data model from one fragment to another via implicit deeplink, but I didn't find a way how to do it. I only found smth like this:

```
val request = NavDeepLinkRequest.Builder
    .fromUri("android-app://androidx.navigation.app/profile".toUri())
    .build()
findNavController().navigate(request)
```

But it has no method to pass a bundle/model or smth like that. Can anyone help ?

EDIT. My case: I need to navigate to the fragment of app module from the fragment of my feature module . That fragment of app module accepts certain data model. I couldn't make dependency to app module, so I don't have direct access to that fragment. Thats why I need implicit deeplink to navigate, and I need to pass a data model.

About anti-pattern, its a huge project and that fragment is used in many places, so I can't change that.

Comment: What is your source of truth for your data model? Do you have a repository that you get the data model from?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I do. But the question is about how to pass that model via implicit deeplink.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#supported_argument_types) and specifically the "Caution: Passing complex data structures over arguments is considered an anti-pattern. Each destination should be responsible for loading UI data based on the minimum necessary information, such as item IDs. This simplifies process recreation and avoids potential data inconsistencies." - you already have a repository that both destinations can access. Just use that.

Comment: @ianhanniballake read the edit.

Comment: @ianhanniballake What if we just want to pass minimum necessary information (itemId) to a fragment present in another module using the deeplink? That fragment will in turn load the complex data structure from resp. repository using that received id.